# The identity element in a sub group

Tags: group-theory

> Find the subgroup of $S_{3}$ generated by
>   $\langle
> \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
>     1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 2 & 1 & 3 
>   \end{smallmatrix}
> \!\!\bigr),
> \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
>     1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 1 & 3 & 2 
>   \end{smallmatrix}
> \!\!\bigr)
> \rangle$

So in general I need to take all the combinations of the elements in the generating set (with their inverses) and see if I get all the elements of the group, or in this case $S_{3}$.

But what about the identity element? Do I need to "build it" from the elements of the generating set? or can I say that each the identity element is already included as "The trivial subgroup of any group is the subgroup $\{ e \}$ consisting of just the identity element."?

Comment: Have you considered applying $(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 2 & 1 & 3 
  \end{smallmatrix})
 $ to itself?

Comment: @Meitar Yes, I saw that it the inverse of itself, but I was asking in general, do I always need to show that I can generate the identity element?

Comment: What ervx stated pretty much takes care of that problem.
In particular, an element being the inverse of itself also got generating the identity element covered...

Answer (score 6):

For any element $x$ in a *finite* group $G$, $x^{|x|}=e$ by definition, so $e$ will automatically be in any generating set. Here $|x|$ denotes the order of $x$ in $G$.

Comment: I think your aswer pretends not to see the real issue: in an infinte group $G$, a positive $\lvert x\rvert$ might not exist.

Comment: That's true. But for any finite group, in particular $S_{3}$, I think the answer is fine. I included the word finite in my post now.

Comment: This answer seems to miss that the *subgroup* generated by a set of elements always contains the identity, regardless of whether the elements have finite order. In the group $(\mathbb Z,+)$ the subgroup $\langle 1\rangle$ is the whole group, not the semigroup of positive integers.

Answer (score 4):

If $S$ is a subset of a group $G$, then the subgroup generated by $S$ is given by
$$\langle S\rangle = \bigcap_{\substack{H\leq G\\S\subseteq H}}H.$$
That is, it is the intersection of every subgroup $H$ containing $S$. In particular, since the identity is in every subgroup, it is in the subgroup generated by any set. One can also use the definition that $\langle S\rangle$ is the elements of the form $s_1s_2\ldots s_i\in G$ where either $s_i$ or $s_i^{-1}$ is in $S$ for all $i$. Then, the empty product would be taken to give the identity, regardless of what $S$ is.

That is, subgroups are automatically closed under inverses and contain the identity, so you do not need to check these things. Note that you could speak of the sub*semigroup* generated by a set of elements - which would be exactly the set of products of the elements - in which case these are not guaranteed and would need to be check, but this is a distinct concept.

Answer (score 2):

> So In general I need to take all the combinations of the elements in
>   the generating set (with their inverses) and see if I get all the
>   elements of the group, or in this case S3.

Let $a$ be one of your generating elements. Then, as you say, $a a^{-1}$ is in the generated subgroup, so yes, the identity element is automatically there. As to whether or not your teacher/grader will require you to note that fact every time, you'll have to ask them.

(There's a subtle question of "the subgroup generated by an empty set of generators" that I'm ignoring. You can probably ignore it too.)

Answer (score 2):

The subgroup generated by a set always contains the identity, by definition (it wouldn't be a *subgroup* if it didn't contain $e$). Milo Brandt's answer gives the formal definition.

Your intuition of $\left<\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 2 & 1 & 3 
  \end{smallmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 1 & 3 & 2 
  \end{smallmatrix}\right)\right>$ as "all combinations of the elements" is correct, but $e$ is a "trivial" combination. You can think of it as the zeroth power.

Put another way, $\left<\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 2 & 1 & 3 
  \end{smallmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 1 & 3 & 2 
  \end{smallmatrix}\right)\right>$ contains (among other things), every integer power of the element $a = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ 2 & 1 & 3 
  \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. That is it contains $\ldots, a^{-2}, a^{-1}, a^0, a^1, a^2, \ldots$. But $a^0$ is $e$ for any group element, by definition.  If that doesn't satisfy you, remember that it must contain both $a$ and $a^{-1}$, so it also contains the product $aa^{-1} =e$.